# Error when compiling jrxml on eclipse in java application

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to generate a pdf on java restful web services applications, using jasper reports. The report was made using jasper studio 6.3.1 plugin for eclipse. The jre I'm using is 1.8.0_112.

When I try to compile the jrxml, using this code:

```
InputStream reportTemplate =httpReq.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(reportPath);
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportTemplate);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 5
Handler.reportError caught:
```

If I compile the report using the plugin, I get the same error when filling the report. The code I'm using for doing that is:

```
InputStream reportTemplate =httpReq.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(reportPath);
JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(reportTemplate);

parameters.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM, jsonDataIs);
parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.ITALY);

JasperPrint pdf = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters);
```

I've tried with eclipse mars2 and neon, getting the same result. The only way I managed to fill in the report was compiling the report in the standalone Jasper Studio 6.3.1 and, once compiled, filling it using the code above in eclipse. But only worked with default font: when changing the font, the report doesn't appear, and I have no console errors.

Comment: You should post the full stacktrace

Comment: the full stacktrace has only those two lines I wrote. I don't know why.

Comment: Hmmm.... Something wrong with your code or IDE. Did you try to debug with attached source code?

Comment: Yes. For example, when I tried to fill the report compiled with the standalone app using wrong data, the stacktrace showed the errors, but now...

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by changing the font to SansSerif. If I put other font, I have the same error on filling the report.

On the other hand, I think the void stacktrace is related with log4j configuration, used by jasperreports.

Thank you for your comments.